# All commit are generating two builds

Tags: svn, continuous-integration, hudson

I'm using Hudson integrated with my SVN repository.
But I don't know why with some reason every commit is generating two commit? Maybe some misconfiguration of clock, server, SVN server?

Some ideas?

As @sbi asks the trigger is every commit in my svn server
and thanks @William Leara I'll try update everything.

Comment: You might want to tell us how your builds are triggered.

Comment: also, there was a bug like this awhile back, but it should not be happening if you are using the latest version of Hudson with the latest SVN Plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One commit causing two builds can occur when Hudson checks the repository for changes too quickly.